# How to make the camera looked cracked

Tags: camera

So I would like to now if it is possible to make the camera looked as if someone cracked it, or put a scratch in it.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/originals/2014/Creative_Wallpaper_The_view_of_the_Earth_through_the_broken_glass_081256_.jpg ?

Comment: yes, something like that

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVr4fPFUr2E

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for it now, we can get a screen crack image (background being of the same single colour, preferably white), and mixing it (Multiply, if background is white) with the render image in the compositor. We can even keyframe the mix factor if we want the crack coming up after some event, say an impact to the camera.